# Bot Framework Prompt style options

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, web-chat

WebChat allows you to style text, for example change color for bubbles from user and bot:

```
    bubbleTextColor: 'white'
    bubbleFromUserTextColor: 'white'
```

But it doesn't work for prompt and OAuth. So i can set white color for all text, but text in OAuth and prompt is still black by default. There is no information about it at [WebChat defaultStyleOptions](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/api/src/defaultStyleOptions.ts).

So how can i change text color for prompt and OAuth cards? And how i can style it in general?

Comment: was my answer helpful ?

Comment: Why don't you just use plain css. Sure, your changes might break after an update of the webchat component but how often will you update that component.

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 0):

Going through the official MS [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) repo, I see you can use the strategy available in [a-branding-webchat-styling](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/02.branding-styling-and-customization/a.branding-web-chat)

This sample introduces `styleSetOptions` and branding your bot through Web Chat via styling.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Refer [official MS doc](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/02.branding-styling-and-customization/a.branding-web-chat#my-required-changes-are-not-all-specified-in-defaultstyleoptionsjs-what-do-i-do-now) and samples as above to learn more:

> ###### My required changes are not all specified in  `defaultStyleOptions.js`, what do I do now?
>
> - Please feel free to  [file a PR](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/new)
>   requesting the feature you want to be able to brand! We welcome your
>   input and are constantly updating  `defaultStyleOptions`  with
>   commonly modified aspects of Web Chat.
> - As a last resort, idiosyncratic styling is available, but not supported by our team. You may use this method by following the
>   [02.branding-styling-and-customization/b.idiosyncratic-manual-styles
>   sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/02.branding-styling-and-customization/b.idiosyncratic-manual-styles/README.md).
>   Please note that using this method creates a  **high likelihood**  of
>   breaking changes when Web Chat releases new code.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but I have read these articles and still did not find the answer. Any changes on font parameters does not affect font in OAuthCards and Prompts. How did you achieved the result with bold font in Oauth card header on first screenshot? Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: here is the Completed code https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/main/samples/02.branding-styling-and-customization/a.branding-web-chat#completed-code   you have make changes to `index.html`

Comment: I see here bubble background color change, but no changes on font, and that was my question about

Comment: you can use `element.style.color` or `<p style="color:blue">This is demo content.</p>` in html, refer [Change chat bubble font and color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-webchat-customization?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&preserve-view=true#change-chat-bubble-font-and-color)